# Vlookup and creating IDs with an array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have an event sign up form on Google forms on which students can select one of many events to sign up for. I'd like to compile the form data so that for each person who signs up for Event A, they are given a ID (i.e. first sign up gets 1, second gets 2, etc.) but I'd like this to be independent from Event B.

I thought of using VLookup to first find the event, and then I thought of having each ID generated with a be a simple `cell + 1` formula, but I'm not sure how to do that with an array. In addition, I'm not sure how to do that with multiple events on the form. Because Event B would need to start from 1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be done with an arrayformula but you can use a formula like this that is copied all the way down the column.  The output is blank if there is no timestamp value in column A:

`=IF(LEN(A2:A),C2&COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C1:C"&ROW(C2)),C2),)`

It assumes the Event ID is held in column C so amend as appropriate for your data

See it working in this example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AiQcEyFKw5sXZ1W7Em5f_gjNx3OC9r1Kw7k4YtbkwAk/edit#gid=0

Comment: I've actually made this simpler by making a new worksheet and filtering the data based on the Event type. Would you know how to add the ID number (starting with 1 on the first visible row and ascending as rows are added)?

Comment: you could try this in row 2 on each event tab: =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),ROW(A2:A)-1,))  Or add leading zeroes using =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),TEXT(ROW(A2:A)-1,"00#"),))

Comment: That counts all the rows, but I would like just the visible rows. For example, filtered data for Event A currently has two entries on rows 2 and 6. The formula you gave displays ID 1 and 5 respectively. I'd like it to show 1 and 2.

Comment: oh, I thought you meant you had used a FILTER formula on a separate tab for each event.  Does the original Sheet I posted not work in the way you want?  I have added Event A onto rows 2 & 6 and the formula in column A returns the values A1 and A2

Answer (score 0):

I used a query function to pull the data out to make separate sheets for each event:

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:E, "select A, B, C, D, E where E='The East Tennessee History Museum'",)`

I then used Chris Hick's function to number the participants

`=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),ROW(A2:A)-1,))`

That worked great!